# Creating new database and insert values in Oracle 10g xe hr account?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I am new to Oracle 10g xe. When I log into hr account, how do I start creating new database and insert values? My case study is a five aside football league, where the organizer wants to know following questions:

1. alphabetical list of all the teams and their players.
2. how many time players have been awarded player of the match?
3. list different types of penalty points which can be awarded?
4. produce a list of all teams playing all other teams indicating who is at home and who is away.

and lot more.

How do I start creating a new database from scratch?

Comment: Just quick: the xe is a database with hr/hr schema and several others pre installed. You can start creating tables in the hr schema.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new user/schema using `create user` clause and then start creating database tables and other objects into this schema. I would not recommend you to exploit `hr` schema, I would keep that schema intact and use it for testing purposes.